# Unity 5 Heighmap Resolution relationship to terrain width / terrain length?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Trying to understand how they relate to the final mesh.

As I understand it,

Terrain width and length is simply the shape/size and within that the resolution determine the vector points/wireframe and how many of them?

So, if i have a width of 500 and length of 500. and height map resolution of 257, then there will be a vector every 2m squared ?

Now, finally, I assume detail resolution and detail resolution per patch have no effect on this at all? but simply the rending process and how the mesh is split up into small chucks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So, if i have a width of 500 and length of 500. and height map
>   resolution of 257, then there will be a vector every 2m squared ?

Yes, you guessed it right. Width and length is the width and length in units of the terrain, whereas heightmap resolution is in pixels. So essentially one pixel on the heightmap will map to ~4 square units (2^2) on the terrain.

> Now, finally, I assume detail resolution and detail resolution per
>   patch have no effect on this at all?

The detail resolution is the resolution of the splat map which contains the data for placement of detail objects like grass, plants, rocks, etc. and is in no way related to the shape of the terrain. Detail patches are just for optimization and LODGroups of detail objects.